# Wont even click when switched to start Silverado 1500

Tags: chevrolet, starter, silverado

Silverado 1500 good battery , lights all good, wont turn over or even click in park  or neutral  . nothing with key turned to start. Any ideas

Comment: What year and engine??

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! The additional information requested by Moab would be greatly appreciated. You could possibly try jumping the terminals at the starter to see if it was the starter or not.

Comment: We need some more details to be able to help without randomly taking a shot at what it could be.have you tried anything besides moving the column shifter ? many systems involved to start the truck and problem with anyone can cause a no crank scenario

Answer (score 0):

See this post on GM no crank condition
http://ricksfreeautorepairadvice.com/no-crank-no-start-3/

Answer (score 0):

there are a few things right off the bat that come to mind.  Try moving the shifter around while holding the key on.  It could be the brake petal sensor or the neutral safety switch.  It could conceivably be your key chip if it has one.